# Close Unity application in HoloLens 2 on close button click

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I have created a unity application using MRTK 2 Toolkit and unity components for the HoloLens2 device, Want to add a functionality to close the application on close button click.

Tried using unity's Application.Quit() api, but it is throwing an exception when close button is clicked.

Comment: What exception is thrown and how are you triggering the call to `Application.Quit()`? Note that this call does not work when running in the Editor.

Comment: Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA8363C278 (GameAssembly.dll) in appName.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000001350.
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA8363C278 (GameAssembly.dll) in appName.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000001350.

Comment: Im adding Application.Quitc() inside a function and that function has been triggered on click event of button. Adding logs before and after Application.Quit(), logs are getting written and when line Application.Quit() is executed the above exception is thrown, I'm not running in editor, I'm deploying the application to HoloLens2 device and testing.

Comment: I found this on the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/access-violation-is-triggered-when-calling-application-dot-quit-in-an-openxr-hololens-2-application